# How to allow users to create reports in ISV apps?

Tags: javascript, html, powerbi-embedded

I want to create a graphical area in my app where user can create reports and they are also allowed to save and share them.

How can I allow create mode in my app?
I am sharing a screenshot of the desired output.

[image]

Comment: [Embed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core) and allow users to [create reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-edit-report-embed-view?tabs=embed-for-your-customers#how-to-create-a-report).

Comment: Hi @AndreyNikolov, I am able to create a report in my app but not able to save that. The file button does not show any option for saving the report. How can I save the created report.

Comment: Call the API `report.save()` it will save the report.